# How can I cast from double to int in jstl?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

This is my jstl version

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

I want to cast from double to int like in Java.

```
${(int)(Math.toDegrees(city.latitude))}
```

But I catch

```
[javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${(int)(Math.toDegrees(city.latitude))}]] with root cause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSTL ... or more precisely EL ... does not support Java explicit type cast syntax.

But in this case you should be able to achieve the result that you want like this:

```
${Double.valueOf(Math.toDegrees(city.latitude)).intValue()}
```

The `intValue()` method gives the same value as a *primitive narrowing* conversion ... which is precisely what casting to `int` would do.